# Find CSS not applied rules

Tags: css

I have a big CSS styles sheet, (about 6500 lines). Is there any way to determine which rules do NOT apply in a given page, (firefox plugin, a web util, or something) ?

Thanks!

PD: Using Firebug I can find which rules apply, but I can't find which rules don't apply.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Firefox, add extension Dust-Me Selectors. It does just that

Comment: this is only for the viewed page, not the entire project/solution/website

Answer (score 0):

In the FireFox add-on, Firebug, CSS rules which are overridden by other rules are crossed out.

Comment: I wanted to find which rules do not apply due to unmatched selectors, not due to overriden rules. Dust-Me does it!

Thanks anyway!

Comment: No problem. The use of firebug may help readers of this question anyway.