# Are there any tools available which can test which CSS rules are unused?

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find CSS not applied rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792623/find-css-not-applied-rules)

I have a CSS file with tons of rules that I know aren't being used because I've completely deleted the elements that used them. But there are a lot and it'd be a huge amount of work testing each rule to see if it's used or not.

Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: I have seen same question 2 times in 2 days. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=remove+unused+css

Comment: Good question, although I think we’ve got a few answers for it already: see e.g. [Find CSS not applied rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/792623/find-css-not-applied-rules)

Comment: 316 questions. Have you *never* noticed the auto-suggested questions that pop up after you enter the question title?